# Flutter 'just_audio' Dependency Error: Unable to Play Local File

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm working on Flutter with the "just_audio" dependency and I'm having an error when trying to play a local file.
I have already made the changes in the pubspec by adding the assets, verified the path "assets/music/song1.mp3," and yet the music playback doesn't work.
The error I'm getting is that the player cannot find the file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class AudioPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioPlayerScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AudioPlayerScreenState createState() => _AudioPlayerScreenState();
}

class _AudioPlayerScreenState extends State<AudioPlayerScreen> {
  late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  bool isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    audioPlayer.setAsset('assets/music/song1.mp3');
    super.initState();
    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void playMusic() async {
    audioPlayer.play();
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = true;
    });
  }

  void pauseMusic() {
    audioPlayer.pause();
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  void stopMusic() {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Reproductor de audio'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            isPlaying
                ? ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: pauseMusic,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.pause_circle),
                  )
                : ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: playMusic,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.play_circle),
                  ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: stopMusic,
              child: const Icon(Icons.stop_circle),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
name: playlist_app
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  just_audio: ^0.9.33

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/music/
```

I want something so simple that when I press the button, it plays the music, and when I pause it, it stops. That's all.

Comment: Please update the question to include your `pubspec.yaml`. Also assert that your code can load an arbitrary asset using the normal RootBundle snippet.

Comment: Please report the bug to https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues

Comment: I add my pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just changed this:

```
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
    ..setAsset('assets/music/song1.mp3');   
  }
```